# How to get the last element in json array in postman

Tags: postman

My code is as follows:

```js
var jsonObject = xml2Json(responseBody);
pm.collectionVariables.set("VehicleVisit",jsonObject['soap:Envelope']['soap:Body'].findVehicleVisitsResponse.findVehicleVisitsResult.allVehicleVisits.WS_VehicleVisit[0].visitNumber);
```

This retrieves the 1st vehicle visit number.

I want to get the last vehicle visit number, can someone help me out?

Note: Each time I send a request the vehicle visits increases, so I need a last visit to use in my next request

Comment: Get the length and -1 to get the last element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something basic like this should work:

```js
var jsonObject = xml2Json(responseBody),
    vehicleVisitArray = jsonObject['soap:Envelope']['soap:Body'].findVehicleVisitsResponse.findVehicleVisitsResult.allVehicleVisits.WS_VehicleVisit;

pm.collectionVariables.set("VehicleVisit", vehicleVisitArray[vehicleVisitArray.length - 1].visitNumber);
```

It's working out the length of the array and then getting the last object from it.

Comment: It works fine to find if there are multiple entries but it is not finding if there is only one entry, I have tried with for loop something like below but it didn't work, can you please suggest?
 for(i = 0; i<vehicleVisitArray.length; i++)
    {
        if(vehicleVisitArray[i].visitNumber)
        {
            pm.collectionVariables.set("VehicleVisit", vehicleVisitArray.visitNumber);
        }
        else
        {
            pm.collectionVariables.set("VehicleVisit", vehicleVisitArray[vehicleVisitArray.length - 1].visitNumber);
        }
    }

Comment: That for loop doesnt look quite right but this is also a different question. Create a new question with the full and complete details - include examples, for when it's an array and when it isn't.